# Agrupar y Sumar en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Buen Dia, tengo una tabla hecha en mysql de la siguiente forma:

```
___________________________________
servicio    | estatus    | cantidad
Agua Potable| ACTIVO     |   4
Agua Potable| EN PROCESO |   3
Agua Potable| RESUELTO   |   2
Agua Servida| ACTIVO     |   3
Agua Servida| INACTIVO   |   1
Agua Servida| EN PROCESO |   5
Agua Servida| RESUELTO   |   3
```

necesito una consulta que me agrupe y sume los registros de esta manera:

---

```
servicio    | estatus    | cantidad
Agua Potable| ACTIVO     |   4
            | EN PROCESO |   3
            | RESUELTO   |   2
Agua Servida| ACTIVO     |   3
            | INACTIVO   |   1
            | EN PROCESO |   5
            | RESUELTO   |   3
```

para luego realizar una grafica

[image]

Anexo el codigo de lo que tengo hecho a ver si puden ayudarme:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$resulta_estatus = $db->query("SELECT servicio, estatus, count(idestatus) as Cantidad FROM reporte GROUP by servicio, estatus");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['estatus', 'Cantidad'],
  <?php
  if($resulta_estatus->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $resulta_estatus->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "['".$row['estatus']."', ".$row['Cantidad']."],";
      }
  }
  ?>
]);
var options = {
      title: 'Indicador de Gestion Mensual',
      hAxis: {title: 'Tipo de Servicio', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

var chart = new   google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columchart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Por favor comparte lo que has intentado. Aunque francamente te diré que usualmente esa porción de la lógica no pertenece en el SQL, sino que usualmente es el cliente que se encarga de hacer eso.

Comment: Un group by y un sum lo resuelven, el tema es que te va a repetir el nombre siempre, si quieres las demas filas en blanco, tienes que resolverlo con el cliente.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la consulta sería

```
SELECT COUNT (estatus) as Total, servicio, status FROM mi_tabla GROUP BY servicio, status; // reemplazar mi_tabla por el nombre de tu tabla.
```

Saludos.

Comment: la consulta sql es la siguiente: `SELECT servicio, estatus, count(idestatus) as Cantidad FROM reporte GROUP by servicio, estatus`

Comment: Tienes razón, por un momento entendí que la suma era lo que se visualizaba en la gráfica.

Comment: Ya consegui que la consulta me haga el grafico correcto en phpmyadmin, lo que estoy tratando de hacer ahora es una rutina en `PHP` y `Google Chart` para hacer lo mismo pero no me da igual

Comment: ya actualice la pegunta

Comment: Que quieres exactamente, puedes visualizar la gráfica, no te toma los datos o que? actualiza también las etiquetas

Comment: visualizo la grafica, pero muestra la data de manera incorrecta, ya que en el eje de `tipo de servicio`  me muestra los `estatus` y no la agrupacion por `servicio` tal como lo tengo en la imagen que anexe en la pregunta. quisiera anexar en este comentario la grafica que me muestra el archivo, pero no se como hacerlo